# How can I change the order of local bookmarks in the stock browser

Tags: browser, samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, bookmarks, stock-browser

The local bookmarks on my stock Browser are in an inconvenient order. The first is one I added recently, then there are a dozen which came with the Android OS, then come the bookmarks I added over the course of a year using this device.

How can I change the order of these bookmarks?  Ideally, I'd like them to be in some order of most recent use. Or, I'd be happy to be able to move the bookmarks around so that I can choose the order myself.

By "local bookmark" I mean the bookmarks I get in stock Browser -- menu -- Bookmarks -- pulldown "Local".

I'm running Android 4.0.3 "Ice Cream Sandwich", which is an over-the-air upgrade from the "Gingerbread" version which came installed on the device. The device is a Samsung Nexus S, unlocked, and used mostly in Canada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bookmarks are kept in an [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database. There is no stock tool to modify them directly. I did, however, find an app that can rearrange the order of your local bookmarks: *[Bookmark Sort & Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.happydroid.bookmarks)*

An issue has been opened about this in *[Allow User To Arrange Bookmarks In ICS Stock Web Browser](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24131)*.

Comment: +1 for the info and the issue report link. The Bookmarks SB app did not work for me,  on my Samsung Nexus S running the stock browser and Ice Cream Sandwich (Android v. 4.0.3). It didn't display any bookmarks, though it did display three empty folders.

Comment: As of Android 4.1.2, and **BookmarkSB** (Sort & Backup) app version 2.39, **BookmarkSB** can now sort my local bookmarks. Note: when I create a bookmark in the Browser, it will by default use my Google account in the "account" field of the bookmark. If I accept that, I won't be able to control the bookmark's order, even if I later change the bookmark's "account" field to be "Local". However, if I set the "account" field to "Local" when I create it, then I can control the bookmark's position in the order using the **BookmarkSB** app.